# Botón sign-in de google no se muestra

Tags: angular, ionic, google-api, google-signin

Estoy probando una aplicación en ionic 4 y angular 8 en el cual tengo que iniciar sesión con Google Sign-In for Websites.
El index de la app es el siguiente

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
  <base href="/" />
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
  <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="viewport-fit=cover, width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
  <meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="CLIENT_ID.apps.googleusercontent.com">
  <title>Auth</title>
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="assets/icon/favicon.png" />
</head>

<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
  <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
</body>

</html>
```

El botón lo quiero poner en un la página home que viene por defecto en un proyecto en blanco.

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>
      Auth
    </ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
  <div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn"></div>
</ion-content>
```

Estoy probando la aplicación de manera local así que la ruta para llegar a la página home es http://localhost:8100/home
pero cuando pongo el botón en la página index este aparece sobre la página home y por lo tanto en todas las páginas que sean creadas lo que no es correcto.
¿Como se puede solucionar el problema para que el botón aparezca en la página home?

**Nota:**
No se requiere el plugin Google Plus

Comment: No hay errores en la consola

Comment: ¿Por que motivo lo estas agregando en en index.html?

Comment: Como dice @cjara, no debe ir en el index, debes de crear una pagina de login.

Answer (score 0):

Debes crear algo asi:

Creas un archivo que se llame `app.routes.ts` con esta estructura:

```js
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},
    {path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent},


    // Esto es lo que hace el lazy load
    {   
      //Cualquier ruta que no sea login, o register debe entrar 
       //aqui
        path: '',
        component: PagesComponent,
        //Este es para seguridad y que si no esta logueado no entre
        //
        canActivate: [LoginGuardGuard],
        loadChildren: './pages/pages.module#PagesModule'
    },

    // Página de error cuando no encuentra una ruta.
    {path: '**', component: NopagefoundComponent}

];
```

Donde el `loadChildren: './pages/pages.module#PagesModule'` carga tus rutas despues de comprobar con `canActivate: [LoginGuardGuard]` que verdaderamente estas logueado(tu servicio de login debe comprobar eso). Así tienes un login separado de tu contenido.

Este es un ejemplo que hice en [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ududyu). Espero que le sirva a alguien.